# HighCharts axis flip on export

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

I have a Highchart in my web application. In the browser it displays normally which is as follows:

[image: Chart display in browser]

But when I export the chart it flips the axis and I end up with the following image:
[image]

Following are the options I am using for my Highchart.

```
var options = ({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'chartDiv'
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: ''
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: ''
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            tickInterval:  7200 * 10000,
            allowDecimals:false,
            labels: {
                format: '{value}',                   
                rotation: 30,
                align: 'left',                  
            },

            title: {
                text: 'Date'
            }
        },
        yAxis: [{
            title: {
                text: 'No. of rings'
            },
            min: 0
        },

        { // Secondary yAxis
            gridLineWidth: 0,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Accumulative Rings',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value} Ring',
                style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
                }
            },
            opposite: true,
        }

        ],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        legend: { backgroundColor: 'rgba(211,223,181,0.6)', layout: 'vertical', align: 'left', verticalAlign: 'top', floating: true, borderWidth: 0, x: 70 },
        plotOptions: {
            spline: {
                marker: {
                    enabled: false
                },

            }               
        }
    });
```

I have three series in my chart, the bar chart can have 0 values.
The data is coming from an ajax service, which I put in an array and then add to chart as follows:

```
chart.addSeries({
    type: 'bar',
    name: 'Rings per day ',
    data: barData,
    pointInterval: mainInterval
});
chart.addSeries({

    type: 'spline',
    name: 'Accumilative rings ',
    data: spline1Data,
    yAxis: 1,
});
chart.addSeries({
    type: 'spline',
    name: 'Planned Progress ',
    data: spline2Data,
    yAxis: 1,
    color: "#FF0000"
});
```

What's wrong with my chart?

Comment: Providing a live demo would have been nice. Any how have you tried **`exporting.chartOptions`**  http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#exporting.chartOptions? Remember that the export function is apart from the chart itself. It could have another options and sometimes in default it already has other options. Like the bar chart whose default view is like the second image you provided.

Comment: `bar` series is the key part. `bar` series forces chart to be rendered flipped. In your case use `column`. It displays differently on your browser because, most probably, you have an old version of Highcharts.

Comment: Thanks @PawełFus that was the solution, please add as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bar` series is the key part. `bar` series forces chart to be rendered flipped. In your case use `column`. It displays differently on your browser because, most probably, you have an old version of Highcharts.